# ss is slow when process option (-p) used

Tags: linux, netstat, ss

When checking for process listening on port using `ss` command, it's slow when compared with (obsolete) `netstat` command.

```
$ time ss -nlp | grep -E ':8081|:8007|:8010'
LISTEN     0      100                      :::8081                    :::*      users:(("java",28681,47))
LISTEN     0      1          ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8007                    :::*      users:(("java",28681,220))
LISTEN     0      100                      :::8010                    :::*      users:(("java",28681,48))

real    0m0.608s
user    0m0.118s
sys 0m0.475s

$ time netstat -nlp | grep -E ':8081|:8007|:8010'
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 :::8081                     :::*                        LISTEN      28681/java          
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8007       :::*                        LISTEN      28681/java          
tcp        0      0 :::8010                     :::*                        LISTEN      28681/java          

real    0m0.146s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.129s
```

Why is 'ss' slow with '-p' option? Is any alternative way to alleviate slowness in `ss`?

Comment: is it really that slow? barely noticeable in real world. plus, you're using grep pipe, which may be slowing the process down. how many tests did you perform? try testing without grep to get better idea of how fast it really is.

Comment: @Bart, I experimented this multiple times. Even without any `grep` also, the result is same with multiple iterations. One of them is as follows: `time ss -nlp &>/dev/null;    

real 0m0.578s
user 0m0.099s
sys 0m0.462s 
time netstat -nlp &> /dev/null;
real 0m0.137s
user 0m0.005s
sys 0m0.130s`

Comment: I've seen it take over a minute on at least one machine, even with It appears that ss is hunting down the pid BEFORE it applies any filtering, which seems like a design oversight.